# SQL - Compare values from two different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two different tables, `update_metadata` with one row that looks like:

```
|Updated_Date|
2020-06-05 00:00:00.0000000
```

and another table where I am querying a single max date from:

```
select max(distinct Date_Col) from data_table
```

Basically, I want to run a procedure `Update_New_Data` if `Updated_Date` < `Date_Col`, i.e if the `data_table` has been updated. But I'm unsure how exactly to set up the query. I tried:

```
WITH data_date AS (select max(distinct Date_Col) FROM data_table),
update_date AS (select Updated_Date from update_metadata)
IF ( update_date < data_date ) 
BEGIN
**procedure SQL query here**
END
```

But I tried it and it looks like I can't use `WITH` with `IF` this way, from this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

How can this be done properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a CTE - just move your queries directly into the `IF` statement as follows:

```
IF (SELECT Updated_Date FROM update_metadata) < (SELECT MAX(Date_Col) FROM data_table) 
BEGIN
  EXEC Update_New_Data;
END;
```

NB: Best practice is to fully qualify all table names and stored procedure names with the schema e.g. `dbo.Update_New_Data`

You don't need `DISTINCT` either.